# p4merge fails when doing a directory diff?

Tags: git, difftool, p4merge

I am trying to use p4merge as my diff/merge tool in git.

But I got a serious problem.

I can use p4merge as a difftool with `git difftool <sha1> <sha1>` it works well. And I can also use it as a mergetool. But when I try to let it do a directory diff like `git difftool -d <sha1> <sha1>` it pops up an error dialog which says:

> Errors:
>   '/var/folders/6s/6sCbckgPGH42yLSh2eXveE+++TI/-Tmp-/git-difftool.9rgKV/left'
>   is (or points to) an invalid file.
>   '/var/folders/6s/6sCbckgPGH42yLSh2eXveE+++TI/-Tmp-/git-difftool.9rgKV/right'
>   is (or points to) an invalid file.
>
> Use 'p4merge -h' for more help.

So is this caused because p4merge doesn't support directory diff? is there any way to fix this?

BTW, this is my `.gitconfig` settings

```
; p4merge settings
; Can't do directory diff?
[difftool "p4merge"]
    cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    trustExitCode = false
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\" 
    trustExitCode = false

[difftool]
    prompt = false
[diff]
    ; tool = kdiff3
    tool = p4merge
[merge]
    ; tool = kdiff3
    tool = p4merge
```

Comment: I use WinMerge for folder diffs. http://winmerge.org

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is confirmed that p4merge does not support a directory diff.

Comment: Could you please include a source? Who confirmed this?

Comment: it's sure not in the manual https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4merge/p4merge.pdf

Comment: it's great when an app DOES advertise what it DOES NOT DO, http://meldmerge.org/help/missing-functionality.html